# Which of the following are Hasse Diagrams?

Tags: graph-theory, relations, order-theory

[image][image][image]

My assumptions are, the first and the last diagrams are Hasse.

Can someone please explain which one is a Hasse and why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**

Hasse diagrams do not have triangles in them.

Comment: So only the first is Hasse?

Comment: Why not third as well?

Comment: Actually, you're right the third one does not form any triangles either